# How to fix the "multi-character literals are not allowed" error in antlr4 lexer rule?

Tags: antlr4, lexer

The rule I am trying to write is:

```
Character : '\u0000'..'\u10FFF';
```

But when trying to run antlr tool against the lexer file where it is defined I get the following error:

```
multi-character literals are not allowed in lexer sets: '\u10FFF'
```

How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try wrapping the multi-char literal with `{` and `}`, and use the v4 style character set `[...]`:

```
Character : [\u0000-\u{10FFF}];
```

From https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/lexer-rules.md#lexer-rule-elements:

> [...] Match one of the characters specified in the character set. Interpret `x-y` as the set of characters between range `x` and `y`, inclusively. The following escaped characters are interpreted as single special characters: `\n`, `\r`, `\b`, `\t`, `\f`, `\uXXXX`, and `\u{XXXXXX}`. To get `]`, `\`, or `-` you must escape them with `\`.

Comment: It's not always necessary to escape `-`. They only should be escaped not on borders. For instance, the following definition works fine: `[+-]`.