# Fixing “multi-character literals are not allowed” error from Antlr3 grammar in Antlr4

Tags: antlr, antlr4, lexer

So,
I'm converting an Antlr3 project, which reads a C++ header file with the lexer, to Antlr4.
I have a problem converting a specific line to the new Antlr4 grammar.

The original line from the Antlr3 grammar is:

```
DEFINE                  :   '#define' ~(' WM_NEWUSER (WM_USER + 2)');
```

Using this will result in a

`multi-character literals are not allowed in lexer sets: 'WM_NEWUSER' error in the antlr4 lexer.`

I tried wrapping the multi-character literals as mentioned in [How to fix the "multi-character literals are not allowed" error in antlr4 lexer rule?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56322449/how-to-fix-the-multi-character-literals-are-not-allowed-error-in-antlr4-lexer)
but it didn't work or I made something wrong.

Edit: Original Grammar

```
grammar Grammar;

@lexer::header {package main;}

WS                      :   (' '|'\t')*;
NEW_LINE                :   '\r'? '\n';
IGNORE_LINES            :   '//@MySQL:IGNORE LINES:' ('0'..'9')+ (' '|'\t')* '\r'? '\n';
IGNORE_LINES2           :   '/*@MySQL:IGNORE LINES:' ('0'..'9')+ (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')* '*/';
IGNORE_KEY              :   '//@MySQL:IGNORE KEY' (' '|'\t')* '\r'? '\n';
IGNORE_KEY2             :   '/*@MySQL:IGNORE KEY' (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')* '*/';
IGNORE_STRUCT           :   '//@MySQL:IGNORE STRUCT' (' '|'\t')* '\r'? '\n';
IGNORE_STRUCT2          :   '/*@MySQL:IGNORE STRUCT' (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')* '*/';
PRIMARY                 :   '//@MySQL:PRIMARY' (' '|'\t')* '\r'? '\n';
PRIMARY2                :   '/*@MySQL:PRIMARY' (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')* '*/';
OPKZ_ZUORD              :   '//@MySQL:OPKZ:' (VARNAME ';')+ (' '|'\t')* '\r'? '\n';
OPKZ_ZUORD2             :   '/*@MySQL:OPKZ:' (VARNAME ';')+ (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')* '*/';
DESC_KEY                :   '//@MySQL:DESC' (' '|'\t')* '\r'? '\n';
DESC_KEY2               :   '/*@MySQL:DESC' (' '|'\t'|'\r'|'\n')* '*/';
MYSQL_KEY_INFO_MULTI    :   '//@MySQL:MULTIKEY:' .* '\n';
MYSQL_KEY_INFO_MULTI2   :   '/*@MySQL:MULTIKEY:' .* '*/';
MYSQL_KEY_INFO_SPECIAL  :   '//@MySQL:SPECIALKEY:' .* '\n';
MYSQL_KEY_INFO_SPECIAL2 :   '/*@MySQL:SPECIALKEY:' .* '*/';
MYSQL_KEY_INSENSITIVE   :   '//@MySQL:INSENSITIVEKEY:' .* '\n';
COMMENT                 :   '/*' .* '*/';
LINE_COMMENT            :   '//' ~('\n'|'\r')* '\r'? '\n';
SIGNED_UNSIGNED         :   'signed'|'unsigned';
TYPE                    :   ('char'|'short'|'int'|'long'|'__int8'|'__int16'|'__int32'|'__int64'|'bool'|'float'|'double');
RESERVE                 :   'reserve'|'szReserve';
TYPEDEF                 :   'typedef';
ENUM                    :   'enum';
STRUCT                  :   'struct';
UNION                   :   'union';
CONST                   :   'const';
DEFINE                  :   '#define' ~(' WM_NEWUSER (WM_USER + 2)');
WM_USER_PLUS_2          :   '#define WM_NEWUSER (WM_USER + 2)' (' '|'\t')* '\r'? '\n';
BRACKET_OPEN            :   '(';
BRACKET_CLOSE           :   ')';
CURLY_BRACE_OPEN        :   '{';
CURLY_BRACE_CLOSE       :   '}';
SQUARE_BRACKET_OPEN     :   '[';
SQUARE_BRACKET_CLOSE    :   ']';
SEMI                    :   ';';
PLUS                    :   '+';
MINUS                   :   '-';
EQUALS                  :   '=';
MAL                     :   '*';
BACKSLASH               :   '\\';
KOMMA                   :   ',';
NUMBER                  :   (('0'..'9')+)|(('0x') (('0'..'9')|('a'..'f')|('A'..'F'))+)|('\'' '\\'? ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z') '\'');
VARNAME                 :       ('a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' ) ('0'..'9' | 'a'..'z' | 'A'..'Z' | '_' )*;
VERODERT                :   '(' (' '|'\t')* VARNAME (' '|'\t')* ('|' (' '|'\t')* VARNAME (' '|'\t')* )* ')';
PRAGMA_ONCE             :   '#pragma' (' '|'\t')+ 'once';
IF_NOT_DEFINED1         :   '#if' (' '|'\t')+ '!' (' '|'\t')* 'defined' (' '|'\t')* VARNAME (' '|'\t')* '\r'? '\n';
IF_DEFINED1             :   '#if' (' '|'\t')+ 'defined' (' '|'\t')* VARNAME (' '|'\t')* '\r'? '\n';
IF_NOT_DEFINED2         :   '#if' (' '|'\t')+ '!' 'defined' (' '|'\t')* '(' (' '|'\t')* VARNAME (' '|'\t')* ')' '\r'? '\n';
IF_DEFINED2             :   '#if' (' '|'\t')+ 'defined' (' '|'\t')* '(' (' '|'\t')* VARNAME (' '|'\t')* ')' '\r'? '\n';
ENDIF                   :   '#endif';
```

So any hint how to resolve my issue?

Comment: Are you sure that is correct? The negation of `' WM_NEWUSER (WM_USER + 2)'` seems odd.

Comment: It's not my code I'm just the one who has to take care, but yes it works. It does exaclty match every #define in the header except `#define WM_NEWUSER (WM_USER + 2)`

Comment: It's been a while since I used ANTLR3, but I don't think it's a valid ANTLR3 lexer rule. Isn't it a parser rule in ANTLR3? Can you post the v3 grammar?

Comment: Original grammar for the lexer added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negation of `' WM_NEWUSER (WM_USER + 2)'` has more or less undefined behaviour in ANTLR 3.

In lexer rules, `~` negates character classes. and will always match a single character. It cannot negate the entire string `' WM_NEWUSER (WM_USER + 2)'`.

Test it yourself with the input: `#define foobar`. There will be 2 tokens:

1. `DEFINE` token, with text `#define_` (note that the `_` is a space after `define`!)
2. `VARNAME` token, with text `foobar`

And if you tokenise `#definefoobar`, you also get 2 tokens:

1. `DEFINE` token, with text `#definef`
2. `VARNAME` token, with text `oobar`

As you can see, the negated part after `'#define'` will always match a single character.

Since what is being negated isn't a proper character set, you might as well have written the rule like this:

```
DEFINE : '#define' .;
```

Yes, that will behave the same as:

```
DEFINE : '#define' ~(' WM_NEWUSER (WM_USER + 2)');
```

A couple of other observations:

- ANTLR3's lexer is bad at backtracking if it cannot create a token at a "late stage". Try tokenising `#define WM_NEWUSER (WM_USER + 23)`. When it stumbles upon the `3`, it will have to give up on the rule `WM_USER_PLUS_2`, but it cannot find another lexer rule for the characters that it already consumed, and will produce an error.
- I see a lot of `.* '\n'` in your lexer: this is a bad habit, try to avoid `.*` whenever you can. Use `~('\n')* '\n'` instead
- the `WS` rule matches an empty string, which is a no-no for lexer rules (there is an infinite amount of empty strings, and might cause your lexer to grind to a halt at runtime)
- your `LINE_COMMENT` forces there to be a line break at the end. This will fail when the end of your input has a line comment (without a line break at the end)

My suggestion: throw that v3 grammar away and either start from scratch or try to find a [open source grammar](https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4) that suits your needs.

Comment: It should also be noted why OP and the original author might have thought it worked as intended (and why that's not the case): The intent was clearly to prevent `#define  WM_NEWUSER (WM_USER + 2)` from being tokenized as two tokens with the first being a `#define` token. And indeed that doesn't happen, it produces a `WM_USER_PLUS_2` token instead as desired. The thing is: it would have done that anyway. That's just the maximal munch rule at work, it has nothing to do with the attempted negation.

Comment: Yeah, it was not clear to me what the OP wanted `#define mu` to be tokenised (probably as a single token, but that is not the case). Anyway, I tried to get the point across that undefined behaviour from ANTLR v3 cannot be converted to v4.

Comment: Right, but my point is that the whole UB-invoking construct was pointless in the first place. OP can just use `DEFINE: '#define' ;` (and could have in ANTLR 3) and the `WM_USER_PLUS_2` rule will still work as intended. And I imagine `#define mu` is supposed to be two tokens. As far as I can tell, the negation is just supposed to be negative lookahead to avoid breaking the `WM_USER_PLUS_2` rule - I don't think it's supposed to actually consume any input.

Comment: Ah, right. And yeah, you might have a point about it being meant as a look ahead.

Comment: Thanks for that detailed answer. I already overhauled a lot of the ANTLR v3 grammar and translated it to (hopefully )proper v4 grammar.  So yeah, I'm pretty close to your advice of throwing it away. I agree with your observations and already fixed them.

Comment: Good to hear that, and you're welcome. Note sepp2k's remarks: you can probably just just do `DEFINE : '#define';` (in both the v3 and v4 grammar) to get the tokens you want.

Comment: I fully agree what was said here, just want to throw in one correction: the negation operation works on character classes, not single characters. Even if you negate a single input char, internally it will be converted to a character class with only one member (the single char) and inverted (by subtracting it from the full Unicode char set).

Comment: @MikeLischke, you're right, of course. Bad wording on my part. Thanks!